# Adding error and message events in phantomjs-node

Tags: node.js, phantomjs

In my project I use [phantomjs-node](https://github.com/amir20/phantomjs-node).

I Wish to Show Errors of execution JS and messages in the console.

For now, I try with the methods next:

```
page.set('onConsoleMessage',function(msg){console.log(msg)});
Page.set('onError',function(msg){console.log(msg)});
```

Can you tell me if I use the right methods?

Comment: You could have started by reading the documentation. It's right there in the link you've added.

Answer (score 1):

From reading docs I suppose you would declare callbacks like this (since they are properties of page object):

```
page.property('onError', function(msg) {
    console.log(msg);
});
```

Comment: Or using `page.on`